# Word for someone who performs task

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

I am working on a record, documenting archived data. I need a single word to describe someone who enters data, disposes of records. Example of a tab I have created: Disposal (Name). I would like to explain what name I need, for example, the person who disposed of the document.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious one that comes to mind is [***data-entry clerk***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_entry_clerk)

> A data entry clerk is a member of staff employed to enter or update
>   data into a computer system.

(which admittedly is more than one word)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities.  The best ones I can think of to fill in "Disposal ____" are:

- clerk
- agent
- specialist
- worker
- delegate